# Fastboot hanging after first command (osx)

Tags: fastboot, macos

My fastboot binary from OSX is responding weirdly and i can't figure out why.

It seems to work great at first since the first command i'm sending works (and this whatever it is) ; but any command after that doesn't. The binary just hangs, and either i can `^C` or open a second terminal and run `fastboot devices`, then the previously pending command will actually run. I've been managing by running a `watch fastboot devices` but it doesn't seem reliable at all.

After some researchs i've been finding [an open bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61933) at AOSP bug tracker but it doesn't seem very urgent to fix it.

- OS             : OSX 10.10.4
- Platform-tools : up-to-date (22)

Any clue, directions about how to solve this ?